# How to assign to an array of variables an array of values in MuPad

Tags: matlab

I want to assign a matrix, vector of symbolic elements, a matrix, vector of values... How?

Something like:

```
matrix([a,b,c,d]) = matrix([1,2,3,4])
```

Which is incorrect in MuPad... So how? Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a syntax in MATLAB or the MuPAD toolbox?

Comment: MuPad toolbox not Matlab :) a b c d are just variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lists instead of matrices:

```
[a,b,c,d] := [1,2,3,4];
```

You could also assign different types, like a matrix:

```
[A,b,c,d] := [matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]),2,3,4];
```